# Prediction Intervals and Alternatives to NHST for testing forecast accuracy between models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, forecasting, prediction-interval

[Here](https://%20https://robjhyndman.com/papers/sst2.pdf) Rob Hyndman says

> In the predictive approach to statistics (McLean, 2000), problems of
> statistical analysis are viewed as prediction problems, and the
> central theme is a statistical (probability) model. A key idea in the
> approach is to use only those models that work, only those producing
> reasonably good predictions. This is clearly a problem of model
> selection rather than significance testing.
>
> A powerful practical alternative to hypothesis testing for forecasting
> methods is to select models using information criteria (e.g., Hyndman
> et al., 2008, ch. 7). The information criterion approach has nothing
> to do with the testing paradigm: there is no null hypothesis, no
> arbitrary threshold $\alpha$ levels and no notion of significance.
> This approach to model selection can be readily extended to model
> ranking and model averaging so that Descartes' dictum can be used. The
> approach can also be extended to forecasting methods that are not
> based on models with computable likelihoods (e.g., Anderson et al.,
> 2000). However, that is altogether another story.
>
> It is not that testing the slope coefficient for zero or residuals for
> normality and independence is never appropriate; or that tests for
> equality of predictive accuracy are never useful. Rather, there is
> widespread confusion, inappropriate use and interpretation of
> significance testing. While statisticians admit the confusion (Hubbard
> and Bayarri, 2003), and while the discipline of statistics is making a
> continuing effort to provide the world with a unified, problem-free
> testing methodology (e.g., Berger, 2003), it is perfectly reasonable
> for a non-statistician to brush aside significance tests altogether,
> tending to use non-test alternatives wherever possible.

He mentions alternatives for model selection, but not for " tests for equality of predictive accuracy ".
What are good alternatives to NHST for  testing forecast prediction accuracy between models?

Lets say I were to go with a Prediction Interval. Is a slimmer interval better?
If I were to go with prediction intervals with a sliding window method, would averaging the prediction intervals be a valid way of comparing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues in your question.

- Prediction intervals: no, narrower intervals are usually not better. After all, we are aiming at a specified coverage. If your PI has the correct coverage, making it narrower will make it lose this. We typically don't want this.

  We typically evaluate central PIs using the [Winkler score](https://forecasting-encyclopedia.com/theory.html#point_forecast_accuracy_measures), which balances calibration (i.e., coverage) and sharpness (i.e., interval width).
- Testing predictive accuracy. Forecasters still quite often only report accuracy KPIs, without formally testing them between methods. If they do test in an NHST framework, they need to account for *multiple forecasting methods* evaluated on *multiple time series*. The current standard is the MCB test ([Koning et al., 2005](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2004.10.003)). I believe that you could, for instance, apply this to Winkler scores as above. This earlier thread may be useful: [How can I determine that a forecast is significantly more accurate than another one? (time series)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/515534/1352)

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading your sources at the moment. I have two follow ups: 1) Often times for means,proportions,etc, confidence intervals and NHST are  equivalent, and we can use CI to interpret our results in a better way than NHST.  I was thinking that in this scenario,  prediction intervals  could be an alternative(but not necessarily equivalent), but I am not sure thats the right track of thinking. 2) Is there any good literature on applying NHST for multivariate time series?

Comment: (1) Hm. Forecasters are usually *much* more interested in PIs than in CIs, after all, [these answer two very different questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info). I would therefore not consider PIs an "alternative" to CIs. (2) Nothing I know of, unfortunately... our econometrics friends may have something. Perhaps you want to ask at [Economics.SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), but best to have a more focused question than just "applying NHST for multivariate time series" - what do you want to test?

Comment: Keep in mind though, that the Winkler score is designed to evaluate a specific type of prediction interval which is defined by quantiles of the predictive distribution.